# Viewing .VCE files on Mac, possible?

Tags: macos, mac

How can I open `.VCE` files on Mac?

Is there a free software product I can download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VCE Player Lite is a good app and is free:

### [VCE Player Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vce-player-lite/id577710321)

For the full version, VCE Player ($14.99) would have more features:

### [Full version VCE Player](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vce-player/id538209222)